# Cannot match any routes in production en

Tags: angular

I don't have any error in the dev env with an Angular 6 application, also no problem with `ng build`, but when I open the index.html in my browser I have this error and only in prod env, no error in dev env

```
main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MultiDB'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MultiDB'
    at e.noMatchError (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.selector (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at e.noMatchError (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.selector (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t.error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at t._error (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
    at polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.bb9d6a4351478c72b831.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
    at d (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
```

my app.routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarsComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My app.module.ts

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    CalendarsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot( {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory
    }),
    FullCalendarModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbPopoverModule,
    SatPopoverModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my header.component.html is :

```
 <li role="presentation">
            <a href="/calendar" class="link">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              {{'calendar' | translate}}
            </a>
          </li>
```

I tried many solutions like outlet in the routing etc but always the same problem

Need help 
Thanks

Comment: Where is `MultiDB` in the routing path defined?

Comment: I didn't understand, you mean that I need to change it in the rooting to be lie this
{ path: 'MultiDB', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'MultiDB/calendar', component: CalendarsComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
  { path: 'MultiDB/login', component: LoginComponent},

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was my bad I forgot to add the name of the folder in server in

```
<base href="/folderName">
```